# Find all natural numbers for which there exists a polynomial that has certain values

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I'm trying to solve this task:

> Find all $n \in {N}$ such that for every such $n$ $\exists$ polynomial $p(x)$ with integer coefficients : $p(d) = (\frac{n}{d})^{2}$ for all natural divisors $d$ of $n$.

So $p(n) = 1$ and $p(1) = n^{2}$. I'm not sure how to approach the problem. Does Lagrange interpolation help here?

Could somebody please give a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your quantifiers.  what does "for every $n$" mean?  Surely $n$ is fixed.

Comment: For instance, $n=1$ is "good" since we can take $p(x)=x$.  Similarly $n=2$ is good since we can take $p(x)=-3x+5$.  (that works since $p(1)=4$ and $p(2)=1$).

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post. I meant "for every such n".

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried?  In my last comment, I believe I showed that $1,2$ are both "good".  Check to see that what I wrote matches what you were trying for.  Then, continue.  What about $n=3$?  $n=4$?  What's the smallest "bad" $n$ you can find?

Comment: Hint: What can you say about the polynomial $x^2p(x)-n^2$?

Comment: It seems like I can use interpolation to write such a polynomial for every n

Comment: @ALiCeP. What $p(x)$ do you suggest for $n=16$?

Comment: @lulu the smallest is n=4 when coefficients aren't integer anymore

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen this new polynomial becomes zero when x=d